# I cannot seem to figure out how to move the location of the legend of my tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to move it into the top left from the top right, but nothing I try works.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Stress-Strain Curve, Mix C}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Strain ,ylabel=Stress (psi), width=12cm, height=8cm]
\addplot+[smooth,color=blue,mark=o]coordinates{
(0.000001,  11)
(0.000045,  38)
(0.000123,  85)
(0.000231,  150)
(0.000371,  230)
(0.000535,  321)
(0.000709,  419)
(0.000897,  524)
(0.001094,  632)
(0.001294,  745)
(0.001502,  862)
(0.001713,  981)
(0.001929,  1103)
(0.002146,  1226)
(0.002365,  1351)
(0.002585,  1478)
(0.002806,  1605)
(0.00303,   1733)
(0.003256,  1861)
(0.003408,  1945)

};
\addlegendentry{Specimen C19E-1}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.

Answer (score 3):

The legend location can be adjusted via

```
every axis legend/.append style={}.
```

So with

```
    every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.0,1.03)}, anchor=south west}
```

you get:

[image]

Alternatively, with

```
every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west}
```

you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%% if you want to change this globally
%\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
%        at={(0.0,1.03)},
%        anchor=south west}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Strain ,ylabel=Stress (psi), width=12cm, height=8cm,
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(0.,1.03)},
        anchor=south west}
]
\addplot+[smooth,color=blue,mark=o]coordinates{
(0.000001,  11)
(0.000045,  38)
(0.000123,  85)
(0.000231,  150)
(0.000371,  230)
(0.000535,  321)
(0.000709,  419)
(0.000897,  524)
(0.001094,  632)
(0.001294,  745)
(0.001502,  862)
(0.001713,  981)
(0.001929,  1103)
(0.002146,  1226)
(0.002365,  1351)
(0.002585,  1478)
(0.002806,  1605)
(0.00303,   1733)
(0.003256,  1861)
(0.003408,  1945)

};
\addlegendentry{Specimen C19E-1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```